# I am trying to add screenshots to extent reports using C# and NUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a base class for all reports. In that class I have added a log status that when it fails should add a screenshot to the extent report. I can not get the screenshot to show up. I also have a class for taking the screenshot with three different methods for doing that. I am not sure what one is the correct to use as it was setup by another person.

```
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Interfaces;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TadsSeleniumTests.Setup
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public abstract class BaseReport : ExtentManager
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void SetupReporting()
        {
            GetInstance();
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void GenerateReport()
        {
            Extent.Flush();
        }

        public void CreateTest(string name)
        {
            Test = Extent.CreateTest(name);
            //Test.Log(Status.Pass, "Pass");
            //Test.Log(Status.Fail, "Fail");
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Public Methods
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public void LogTestStatus()
        {
            var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
            var stacktrace = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace)
                                 ? ""
                                 : $"{TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace}";

            var message = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message)
                              ? ""
                              : $"{TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message}";
            Status logStatus;

            switch (status)
            {
                case TestStatus.Failed:
                    logStatus = Status.Fail;
                    break;
                case TestStatus.Inconclusive:
                    logStatus = Status.Warning;
                    break;
                case TestStatus.Skipped:
                    logStatus = Status.Skip;
                    break;
                default:
                    logStatus = Status.Pass;
                    break;
            }

            if (status==NUnit.Framework.Interfaces.TestStatus.Failed)
            {
                Test.Log(logStatus, "<b>" + "ERROR MESSAGE: " + "</b>" + message);
                Test.Log(logStatus, "<b>" + "STACKTRACE: " + "</b>" + stacktrace);

                // Take a screenshot and attach it to report on failure, ideas here, can't get any of them working yet:
                string screenShotPath = TakeScreenshot.Capture(Driver, "FAILURE");
                Test.Log(logStatus, "Screenshot: " + Test.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath));
                Test.Fail("details", MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath).Build());
            }

            else
            {
                Test.Log(logStatus, "Test ended with " + "<b>" + logStatus + "</b>");
            }



        }

using System;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Reflection;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;


namespace TadsSeleniumTests.Setup
{
    public class TakeScreenshot
    {
        public static ExtentTest Test;

        protected static string Capture(IWebDriver driver, string v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        //       public static string Capture(IWebDriver driver, string screenShotName)
        //       {
        //           ITakesScreenshot ts = (ITakesScreenshot)driver;
        //           Screenshot screenshot = ts.GetScreenshot();
        //           string pth = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
        //           string finalpth = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin")) + "ErrorScreenshots\\" + screenShotName + ".png";
        //           string localpath = new Uri(finalpth).LocalPath;
        //            screenshot.SaveAsFile(localpath, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
        //           var mediaModel = MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath(finalpth).Build();
        //           Test.Fail(screenShotName, mediaModel);
        //
        //           return localpath;


        //        public static string Capture1(IWebDriver edriver, string screenshotName)
        //        {
        //           var screenshot = edriver.TakeScreenshot();
        //           string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM-d-HH.mm");
        //           var filePath = "C:\\Users\\..";
        //            screenshot.SaveAsFile(filePath + currentTime + screenshotName + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
        //            return filePath;


        public static string ScreenShot(IWebDriver wdriver, string imgName)
        {
            var screenshot = wdriver.TakeScreenshot();
            string localpath = "C:\\Users\\.." + imgName + ".png";
            screenshot.SaveAsFile(localpath, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

            return localpath;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added the ScreenShot class to the original comment

Comment: Do you get an error? Or does the file just not save?

Comment: I am not getting any error, the files are not saving in the folder specified.

Comment: First thing I would check, when you step through the code, does the value in the variable that holds your filepath look correct? Have you tried just hardcoding a path that you know is on your local machine as a test? If that works then you know you're doing something messed up in building your path.